# How to get and display last row value form many table in one to Many relationship

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.7

My two table `Member` and `Deposit` there has  **one to many** relationship one member has multiple deposit in `Deposit` table i want to display last record of deposit table when i call all Member or a single Member.

**This is my `Member` Table**

```
1.id,
2.name,
3.phone,
4.account_no,
5.ac_open_date,
6.ac_close_date,
7.status,
8........
```

**My `Deposit` Table**

```
1.meber_id,
2.deposit_date,
3.deposit_amount,
4.total_amount,
5..........
```

**My Controller Code**

```
$member = Member::with(['Deposit'=>function($query){$query->select('*')->latest('deposit_date')->limit(1);}])->where('status','ready')->get();
```

if i return $member variable then show my aspect data ok. but when i show this in my blade file this way ...

**blade section**

```
<td>{{ $member->name }}</td>
 <td>{{ $member->account_no }}</td>
 <td>{{ $member->phone }}</td>
<td>{{ $member->deposit->total_amount}}</td>
```

when i call the `Deposit` model to display to `deposit` table last row records then show the error.

> "Property [total_amount] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs........

what can i do .please help me anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try `{{ $member->deposit->first()->total_amount}}`.

`$member->deposit` returns a collection of all deposits of the member, even if there is only one.

Comment: **@Daniel Chen**  i have do that but displaying first record of `Deposit` table not last record. but i need last record .

Comment: @Md.AzharulIslam use `last()` instead of `first()` in that case.

Comment: **@Daniel Chen**  my previous all are working ok, my another stage i need to match some criteria  with  `Member` table and `Deposit` table/model method. how can i add another `->where()` clause in `Deposit`  table/model method.Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you update the `total_amount` for every transaction for a member with the total Deposits till now, if so, I suggest to add new attribute for the `Member` table and save this value on it, so you can get it easily, and you can update it when needed.

Comment: **`@Amir Helmy`** i want to display last record of  `Deposit` table table not only `total_amount` but also the column depend on my need.